# when i am going to another page then i want to go back to homepage specified component, how to go?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

So, i want to go to homepage's specific component when i clicked my website navbar manu.First clicked go homepage but not going specific component. when second click the navbar then go the specifics component.

```
This is homepage coding:
```

```
import React from 'react';
import About from '../Component/About/About';
import Contact from '../Component/Contact/Contact';
import Home from '../Component/Home/Home';
import Services from '../Component/Services/Services';
import Solution from '../Component/Solution/Solution';
import Header from '../Component/Header/Header';

const Homepage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <Header/> */}
            <Home/>
            <About/> 
            <Solution/>
            <Services/>
            <Contact/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage;
```

```
This is another page,
servicespage code here:
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ServicesAllData } from '../AllData/ServicesAllInfo';
import { t } from 'i18next';


const Servicespage = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    let data = ServicesAllData[id];

    return (
        <section className=''>
            <div className='text-center `your text`pt-32 m-10'>
                <i className='pt-16 text-9xl'>{data.icon}</i>
                <h2 className='sm:text-lg md:text-xl xl:text-2xl font-bold'>{data.name}</h2>
                <p className='font-semibold sm:text-lg md:text-xl lg:text-2xl pt-6 text-center'>{t(data.description)}</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Servicespage;
```

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear if you are saying there is some issue with the provided code snippet that you are trying to resolve. Can you edit the post to clarify what any *specific* programming problem you have is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should show how you coded out your routes, it helps in improving and understanding what you are asking for.